# Pejorative form of flourish

Tags: word-request

In a written paper, my teacher pointed out a mistake I made, which was using

> ... problems which flourish ..

Apparently problems can't *flourish* , I forgot to ask why but I'm assuming because flourish has a positive connotation.

So my question is: What is the pejorative counterpart to the word *flourish* (which would be appropriate for my example of course)?

Comment: Also; is counterpart to correct or should it be counterpart of?

Comment: It doesn't fit the specific usage here, but in other contexts, ***brandish*** can be a more negative version of ***flourish***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I don't think using 'problems that flourish' is actually bad here. I would actually use it in non-work writing. But she is correct that it is a positive word.

Maybe you can use 'proliferate': which means to increase quickly and is more negative.

If you can include more of the sentence I can tell you if that would fit well..

Comment: Keep in mind I'm still a rookie so it's not quite Shakespearean, but it was: 'The aim of this report is to describe the various problems which flourish in the city of ...'

Comment: Gotta say, I think your teacher is wrong on this one... I would have written this sentence. I would suggest "The aim of this report is to describe the various problems plaguing the city of..."

Comment: It would certainly not be the first time. I however agree that plaguing is more fitting/elegant.

Comment: I feel the appropriateness of using flourish in this instance depends on the tone and intent of the writing overall, is it satirical or factual? In either case I feel the correctness would be based on the overall purpose and intended audience of the writing- seeing only this sentence takes it out of context.

Comment: @Practice4CPE: You could consider words like *bedevil, plague,* etc., but you might think they're a bit "flowery" for a [technical?] report. Only you know if you want to emphasise the fact that they *[continue to] adversely the inhabitants*, or that pre-existing problems are *becoming more acute*, or that there are *more [different] problems arising*, etc.

Comment: I very much disagree; I don't think the teacher was wrong at all.  I think Robert has it right in his answer; "flourish" means to grow in a positive way, so problems cannot possible flourish. I would use "proliferate" or a synonym of it, or any of the words suggested on this question--that much is correct. But your teacher is absolutely right that you should not have used *flourish*. It would be a perfectly appropriate word in positive contexts, but not here.

Comment: I think you will commonly see uses of positive connotative words being used in negative contexts to add flair to the writing. For example: "Diseases flourish in the dark underbelly of the city." - having the comparison available adds a little bit of tension to the writing. The teacher was definitely right to point out the meaning of the word to make sure that the student was going for the effect intentionally -- but to flat out tell a student that it is incorrect under any circumstance is not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The word *flourish* means to grow, spread, or develop in a prosperous way. So you wouldn't say a problem is *flourishing,* unless you are saying that the problem spreading is a good thing (or maybe telling the story from the problem's point of view as the protagonist — *grin*).

You need a word that suggests something is spreading, but in a negative (or at least neutral) way.

A few suggestions: infecting, permeating, contaminating, infiltrating.

But you can also change the context a bit by describing the causal effect on the city — hurting, plaguing, distressing, troubling, poisoning — in a way that take it away from trying to make the act of *spreading* pejorative.

Answer (score 2):

A problem that continues to get worse over time until it is dealt with could be described as [*festering*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fester?s=t) (sense 2: to putrefy or rot).